# Where does image.expected command search image?

Tags: automation, rpa, g1ant

I have downloaded some image from the web and later I am opening that particular image using my robot but when I use image.expected command it gives false always doesn't matter whether I am searching on an absolute window or relative window. 
In this robot, at an absolute window would be that particular image when I am using image.expected command i.e. on "relative true" argument it should return true but its giving me false.

```
♥image = ♥environment⟦USERPROFILE⟧\Desktop\image.png
file.download https://jeremykun.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/img49.png filename ♥image
program ♥image
image.expected ♥image result ♥isPresent relative false
dialog ♥isPresent
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, it searches in a region equal to the current screen area. You can also specify the coordinates to search in with the `screensearcharea` argument. Quoting from the [manual](https://manual.g1ant.com/G1ANT.Addons/G1ANT.Addon.Images/Commands/ImageExpectedCommand.md):

> Narrows the search area to a rectangle specified by coordinates in the x0⫽y0⫽x1⫽y1 format, where x0⫽y0 and x1⫽y1 are the pixel coordinates in the top left corner and the bottom right corner of the rectangle, respectively.

Maybe set a few seconds of delay before you `image.expected` command, it could be that image software is slow to start up.

Comment: then it should pick the coordinates of that image, as it would be on the current screen.